# Aligning text in iText in a single row

Tags: java, itext

What is the best way to create a row of text that will have two elements aligned to an imaginary line? Like this (four rows given to illustrate the point better):

```
   1. some random text
  34. some more random text
 764. here's even more random text
4594. it just never ends
```

Imaginary line would go trough the dots, or the space after them. The numbers have right alignment, and the text has left alignment.

I do not want to use a list because elements may not be in order, and it has certain limitation with setting the line spacing.

Comment: Have you considered to use a two-column table?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a PdfPTable with 2 columns, the first right aligned and the last left aligned. Then set the designer padding on the cells content.
For example:

```
PdfPTable tbl = new PdfPTable(2);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("1."));
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
cell.disableBorderSide(Rectangle.BOX);
tbl.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("some random text"));
cell.disableBorderSide(Rectangle.BOX);
tbl.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("34."));
cell.disableBorderSide(Rectangle.BOX);
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
tbl.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("some more random text"));
cell.disableBorderSide(Rectangle.BOX);
tbl.addCell(cell);
```

You can see that cell border are disabled (`disableBorderSide` method).
You can also adjust the minimum height of cells using `setMinimumHeight` method.

Comment: Would that table affect the vertical and horizontal positioning of the text? Or, in other words, can I make borders be 0 pts thick?